# How to setup Ioc (Autofac) with Sitecore MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, autofac, sitecore8

Does any one know how to setup correct IoC (Autofac) and use it with Sitecore MVC ?
I have created a specific Pipeline but it seams like resolving doesn't work when sitecore render page (Controller rendering).

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <initialize>
                <processor type="MyLib.AutofacProcessor, MyLib" />
            </initialize>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

---

```cs
public class AutofacProcessor
{
    public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        AutofacProcessor.Start();
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<MyService>().As<IMyService>().PropertiesAutowired();

        var container = builder.Build();
        IDependencyResolver resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

But my property in controller is null when sitecore call it.
How to register it in Sitecore term ? In Regular ASP MVC it is quite easy.

Answer (score 5):

You also need to override Sitecore's default ControllerFactory.

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeControllerFactory, Sitecore.Mvc"/>
```

Here's an example for NInject, it should be easily modified to do the same with AutoFAC: http://blog.istern.dk/2012/10/23/sitecore-mvc-new-ninject-controller-factory-clean-version/

Comment: thanks you in general it is clear.  but I really have a problem with implement KernelFactory and  DefaultControllerFactory how it should looks like for Autofac ?

Comment: You need to replace the DefaultControllerFactory with an AutoFacControllerFactory. In short form, the only method you need to override in there, would be GetControllerInstance - and have that one resolve the requested type (in the controllerType argument) via AutoFac.

Comment: it is a little bit complicated to implement, based on article it is required load all sitecore  NinjectKernelFactory via, I really afraid make it in a wrong way.

Answer (score 4):

I create a blog post around how to use Autofac with Sitecore MVC in order to resolve dependencies:
http://sitecorecorner.com/2016/01/20/sitecore-mvc-autofac-dependency-resolution/

You can find the code on [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/nsgocev/sitecore-mvc-autofac-dependency-resolver/src)

The basic idea is to create an `AutofacContainerFactory` - to create your Container. `AutofacControllerFactory` - which you are going to use to resolve the dependancy and Hijack the `<processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeControllerFactory, Sitecore.Mvc">`
processor.